# How to set a variable value in a Flask HTML template

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am trying to a assign a value to a WTForm field within the HTML template. I need to do it this way as the value assigned will depend on what iteration of the for loop it is in. Any other way of passing a value back to the python script will work as well.

I am currently getting an error. I am trying to assign the record field of the form equal to the id of the record it is currently viewing.

Below is the code:

```
<div class="modal-body">
                <p>Name of Training: {{ record.training_name }}</p>
                <p>Name of Provider: {{ record.training_provider }}</p>
                <p>Date of Training: {{ record.date_submitted.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') }}</p>
                <p>CPD Hours: {{ record.cpd }}</p>
                <p>Certificate: <a href="{{ url_for('static', filename='certificates/'+record.certificate_path) }}" target="_blank">View</a></p>
                <form action="" method="post">
                  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                  <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      {{ form.reason(class="form-control", placeholder="Reason for Denial (if applicable)") }}
                      {% set form.record.data=record.id %}
                    </div>
                  </fieldset>
```

When attempting to use the solution above I am getting the following error: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got '.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly:

```
{{ form.record(value=record.id, class="d-none") }}
```

instead of

```
{% set form.record.data=record.id %}
```

Comment: This is good, but the field shows this way. I want it to be hidden

Comment: I'm assuming you're using bootstrap with the **form-control** class. Add **d-none** to have the field hidden